# DotNetBrowser in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, dotnetbrowser

Is it possible to to use DotNetBrowser through an ASP.net environment?
I have used it in my Winforms application to load a web page behind the scenes so that I can access HTML code but I now have a need to run the same functions via a WebForms (code behind).

Can this be done with DotNetBrowser and if it can are there any ASP.net examples available?

Comment: You need to call jquery function?

Comment: Are you screen scraping. You could use the WebClient class. I think this link might help. https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070601-1.shtml